# I am trying to fetch objects from a main object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, stack

I am trying to fetch objects from a main object. An array in the main object holds 
these other objects, I can access the first element by calling '`oData.events.event[0]`' but I would like to loop through to get `[1], [2], [3]` and so on.

```
//this works
var collection = oData.events.event[0];
$("<li>description: " + collection.description + "</li>").appendTo("#shower");


//this does not work :(

var collection = oData.events.event[0];

var output = "<ul>";

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)

{

    output += "<li>" + collection.description + "</li>";

    $(output).appendTo("#shower");

    collection = collection + 1 //shift to next array

}

output += "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use a foreach loop

```
oData.events.event.forEach(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Alternatively, try jQuery's .each() function:

```
$.each(oData.events.event, function(index, value) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value );
});
```

EDIT: It's worth noting that the output of these calls will be an object - you still have to access the data beneath the objects you've looped to!

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LnL847ow/) here - however, you can do something like this...

```
var oData = {
    events: {
        event: [{ description: '1' },
                { description: '2' },
                { description: '3' }]
    }
}

var collection = oData.events.event;
var output = "<ul>";

collection.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    output += "<li>" + item.description + "</li>";
    if (i === arr.length-1) {
        output += "</ul>";
        $("#shower").append(output);
    }
});
```